# Publishing alarm event to Nest cloud

Tags: nest-api

I'm researching Nest integration for a product we've built, and I'm wondering if my desired use-case is supported.

Our device is a simple sensor that has 2 states: "ok" and "problem". Ideally, we'd like to publish updates to this state (i.e. write the state variable) for our device to the Nest cloud and have an alert generated via the Nest mobile app... we'd simply like to integrate into the Nest ecosystem and have alerts from our sensor displayed via the Nest mobile app.

I've been unsuccessful in finding a way to do this after reading the "documentation" and "api" sections of the developers site.

Is this type of integration possible and supported?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Currently Nest does not support uploading data other than resource usage. With the pre-announced [Weave API](https://developers.nest.com/documentation/weave/weave-overview) profiles will be supported, and thus a device could publish an alarm profile.

Comment: Thx... just what I was looking for.